# runOnUiThread kills App when rotating screen

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, autorotate, activity-lifecycle

I think I know why this happens.

When rotating the screen the Activity gets destroyed and recreated and the `runOnUiThread()` method is referencing the old(destroyed) Activity which isn't valid anymore and so android throws a `runtimeexception`.

To demonstrate this I have this code:

```
@ContentView(R.layout.activity_start)
public class StartActivity extends RoboSherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Inject
    private EventManager eventManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment newFragment = new WelcomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment).commit();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        //Do some short initialization here like read shared prefs
                        //and then decide for example whether to login or skip the login

                        //If the rotation happens while sleeping the app will certainly crash
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                addFragmentToStack();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    void addFragmentToStack() {
        Fragment newFragment = new LoginOrRegisterFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Do I have to use an `asynctask` for some easy task like that? If so how I handle the rotation then? Because the callback reference would be faulty either.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this

new Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable(){

             if(!isFinishing()){
                  addFragmentToStack();
               }
          },200);
```

instead of your thread code

`isFinishing()` is called when the activity is in the process of being destoryed

It seems that all you're trying to do is to make the task executed after 200 ms have passed.
there is no need to open a new thread for that, a handler will do
2ndly if you want to ensure that the code will be executed on the main thread
you create the handler calling for the main looper
`Handler(getMainLooper())` and it will make this handler execute its task on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask will generate the same crash. You can Simply override `onPause()` and find a way to notify the thread that Activity is about to be destroyed. Like checking for null value of a variable.

```
public void run() {
       if(someVariable != null)
           addFragmentToStack();
}
```

Or you can use a callback fragment (without view) to keep track of configuration change. This [article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) is a great way to start. This method I prefer because it is  a very clean approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by using a retain fragment where I store a reference to the Activity on every OnCreate e.g. retainFragment.activity = this; . In runOnUiThread I check if the retained reference is the current Activity e.g. if (retainFragment.activity == MainActivity.this)..